# Date List Not Counting Current Month

Tags: python, list, datetime, dataframe, date-range

I am trying to make a date list like this:

```
date_list
Out[27]: 
['Sep 2014',
 'Oct 2014',
 'Nov 2014',
 'Dec 2014',
 'Jan 2015',
 'Feb 2015',
 'Mar 2015',
 'Apr 2015',
 'May 2015',
 'Jun 2015',
 'Jul 2015',
 'Aug 2015']
```

But for some reason my code is cutting out August. I take a chunk of code from the last year until now.

I made an if statement because if it was the last day of the month it would only take 11 of the last months rather than 12.

```
range_max = datetime.datetime.now() 
date = datetime.datetime.now()

if datetime.datetime.now().day == calendar.monthrange(date.year, date.month)[1]:
    range_min = range_max - pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)+ pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(days=1)
else:
    range_min = range_max - pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)+ pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd(1) + pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(days=1)
```

Then I take the slice out of the data frame

```
df = df[(df['recvd_dttm'] >= range_min) & 
               (df['recvd_dttm'] <= range_max)]
```

Then I make my date_list.

```
date_list = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start = range_min, end = range_max, freq='M'))
print date_list
date_list = date_list.index.to_series().apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strftime(x, '%b %Y')).tolist()
```

However, this is printing

```
date_list
Out[27]: 
['Sep 2014',
 'Oct 2014',
 'Nov 2014',
 'Dec 2014',
 'Jan 2015',
 'Feb 2015',
 'Mar 2015',
 'Apr 2015',
 'May 2015',
 'Jun 2015',
 'Jul 2015']
```

Does anyone know why it's not calling August data? This was just working the other day, I don't understand what's gone wrong. The August data is definitely in the data frame I am pulling for this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When today is not the last day of the month, then range_min is set to the last day of the month one year ago. So the dates it is giving when I run it are:

```
[2014-09-30 00:20:35.774489, 
 2014-10-31 00:20:35.774489, 
 2014-11-30 00:20:35.774489, 
 ..., 
 2015-07-31 00:20:35.774489]
```

I'm not an expert with pandas but most ranges in python run to one less than what you'd expect, and since it's not yet the last day of August and you are adding one month each time then I think you need to add an additional month here:

```
date_list = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start = range_min, end = range_max + pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(months = 1), freq='M'))
```

Then your dates run to the end of August, if that is what you want?